# How to disable ARC for some files for ALL targets in a project?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, manual-retain-release

I checked that [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) that works well (adding in compile source by tapping on Enter on keyboard and adding "-fno-objc-arc"), but my problem is that I have next to 80 targets in my projects.

I would like to know if there is a way to exclude the files for all the 80 targets ?

Thanks in advance.